# Error creating RESTful Web Service trying to read a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, rest

I am trying to create a RESTful Web Service with  C#/ ASP .Net Web API. I have created a basic service that displays an html page based on examples I've seen
on the web with a `HomeController`. Now I am now trying to create a service that reads from a database and I am getting an error:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MyController'. 
Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."
,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","
...
":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'MyDatabase'.","ExceptionType"
:"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException","StackTrace":"
```

`MyController` has a parameterless constructor:

```
public MyController()
{
    // get values from database
    MyData model = db.MyData.Find(); // exception thrown here
}
```

`MyData` is a simple class, a bunch of properties.

The Web.config file has the correct connection string. ( I use this db frequently in other applications)

I am mystified by the error message in that it say there is an error creating a table. I am only trying to read.
 Even so, as I said, the  connection string is correct and it should be able to create a table if it wants to.

What can you suggest?

```
public partial class MyData
{
    private const string NONE = "(None)";

    public MyData(int p1, string p2, string p3, string p4)
    {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.p3 = p3;
        this.p4 = p4;
    }

    [Key]
    public int MyId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    private String _MyName;
    [DisplayName("My Name")]
    public string MyName
    {
        get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_MyName) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_MyName))
            {
                return NONE;
            }
            else
            {
                return _MyName;
            }

        }
        set
        {
            _MyName = value;
        }
    }

    [Key]

    [StringLength(10)]
    private string _MyNumber;
    [DisplayName("My Number")]
    public string MyNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_MyNumber) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_MyNumber))
            {
                return NONE;
            }
            else
            {
                return _MyNumber;
            }

        }
        set
        {
            _MyNumber = value;
        }
    }

    [StringLength(255)]
    private string _MyStatus;
    private int p1;
    private string p2;
    private string p3;
    private string p4;

    [DisplayName("My Status")]
    public string MyStatus
    {
        get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_MyStatus) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_MyStatus))
            {
                return NONE;
            }
            else
            {
                return _MyStatus;
            }

        }
        set
        {
            _MyStatus = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you read the error message? `permission denied`. whatever user you're connecting to the db as doesn't have the rights to do that.

Comment: Does this table exist in your database currently?

Comment: Are you using dependency injection?

Comment: What you are using for database access entity framework?

Comment: @Praveen Paulose: I guess this is the problem. Suppose I have a table `tblMyData`. How do I connect to it?

Comment: Can you share your class file for MyData?

Comment: I have added it to OP

Comment: @mickey Added an answer to do the mapping. Does it solve your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the attribute Table above your class MyData. This will map the class MyData to tblMyData.

```
[Table("tblMyData")]
public partial class MyData
{
    //class code here
}
```

Currently, since there is no mapping, your code is trying to create a table by the name MyData and your connection string credentials do not have enough permissions to create a table.